# How to select a line chart by clicking somewhere else than a datapoint in echarts?

Tags: data-visualization, linechart, echarts, apache-echarts

I am using **echarts** to visualize multiple line-charts. When I click exactly on a datapoint I am able to select a specific line chart. However If I click elsewhere on the line, where there in no datapoint associated, the chart in not selected. I know there is a focus feature by hovering the mouse. I want the same functionality using the click event.
I am using the following method, but I am not sure how to implement it.

```
    myChart.getZr().on('click', params => {
        //to be implemented

     })
```

Here is the configuration example for the hovering effect on echarts:
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=multiple-x-axis

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with filled-area

I put `areaStyle: {}` in series' option
then add the following event handler like [this](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=multiple-x-axis&lang=js&code=MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOEYF4YG0DkBiArACwDsADAMIBs2ANDHgKIOUvUC6A3AFAgAOUAS3DoYAby4w4IREgBcUmRBoSYUENMG954yZKhIBAc0MBTOfTDgTtFZICGADwEQACiAFgoZ7bd1QAnrwm8tjASCAQENi-AL4qMcqS8CamYAAm2gkqhgYZYr5qWjBkiboARiBQagC28vik8aUOAIJOEPKYvjq6eoHB9MB2XobI_jY99m0AKgLAANY-E7p28EZgAOoCUAAWADJ2ZSbw8voAria-kllLjs67Hv3dS-AAWmYg8gBmKxAmpUurMAmADKAWSiyWugQyHk0JQmAAjGxLro4ktrhNbq53J5vPlITB4AcjhCCZ9kNUhl5zJ9TmBgIJhAAKXh2JB2aoQACU-IJuiQJigpyQYBgTJRBOwLgFwAEvC2QyEovoMAA1BLIaz2ZyAHQANxW5zVGqWLLZHIgOt-BhMEAAIkM7DrkmBDDsYAB-eiALH_sGqYFqLVazAJbQ6oHZMKQ2Dq0o6YCFsFyTboudw-TA0ZCsz0MT0APT5gMCqqhpAAWjWyAuSzjEY62AATKQEZRywjaPRm63y43O02W22AMz97ttwijwfl_CTnvUOgDnvEWdtgAcK_LAE4NwjSDuOwux-2-8jc_9eT0AkEQoNhqNxpjprMFhfMatDBstnticdVEhziiebLG09xAqSEyvO8Xw_H8GqAiCYKPCmcKwtIyAQFGp7ZoB56TM4bgeNS4E9EShy_k8kLkkglJVHitL0oyopmtq3KvgSJbCkxKY9FKMpygqjGSH66oZj0ga6ga8BGiJomSMxQbWqG9qOs6Jiuu6XrYL6_riZailho6mGxvGibJrJaYpjmExWVcuEwIWxaCoIZiVh-1YonWdgNt2-DtrOvl9oeLa-SOQUIr5E5hb5M5ReW85dsF5bLrF66xdusW7v57YHgl4XHtgWFXCobClP4rTOB0XQole_TYJJ5zRLmxWlPp7RYFVSxgBytXSiYsryhGjFMj5XIPpefQhPBY26C0bQAJLpCYDjyAidkQNU6g7Cc_6wUsJjVLw2x2BAFVsbo5LAKcbXYK1jXWXZnmVQSjY6pQdD4Dqm50JuOqkHQjaUDqhD_auOrEHQZBg3QCLEB9b0wAiq4vY2dCEKD4MI6Dq50IDf0wC9Q4oiVKJsiYdigv44JiFZQEUZIXXVD1fEDYq4DDYOo12TVk0PNNkjrZt2zbecdn7Ydx2nXT50gJd123ThHmOk9kJDp971qwjCI6qtmNQzAaM6kOOM_Sj-NDlr8OEID8P4B9wO6_bu6G3QpBg0TKJ2aT5OIZksTFVwMTcFwwfcbJEzVP45BHUgUA6qYUAvEgTJcjqbOhKs8ydvRDJKmKuk8lLYdhwA8mUABWfWx3MJj-BA8m6hGSDxynnwCPA1JMtX_joAAfDAXc6h4wBSWktrikXE-QtgAD6099dPHhAkg09Ji3bcd13vcBuaDdsvHmBd4Vk_H8GNoQAto8ODAACEGB0qPrdAmkLfIAwdjANsnc11vhfH3_kigEgNIEwzoQCGCZHwRip8lKYF0jqRu-9D6h3_ifVqF8loxgZiYMyKCJ7IP_jEHBuDrJpiAA)

```
myChart.getZr().on('click', function (params) {
                                Object.keys(params.target).filter(key => key.includes(
                                    '__ec_inner_')).filter(key => params.target[key]
                                    .seriesIndex != undefined).forEach(key => {
                                            console.log(option.series[params.target[key]
                                                .seriesIndex].name)
                                    
                                })
                            });
```